# Can I look at both the original content of a file and the file being changed at the same time?

Tags: git

When I make some changes to a file, I sometimes would like to look at both the original file and the file being changed by me, so that I know what I have just changed i.e what it was like before I change it.

Since the working directory can only have a single version of the file, is it possible to do that under git?

or shall I do that outside git, e.g. by copying the original file somewhere else?

Or shall i change my work style to avoid looking at the original file while changing it, by some other better work style?

Thanks.

Comment: Read about [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Comment: Are you talking about git diff ?

Comment: Any method is welcome. @Fall

Answer (score 2):

`git show HEAD:path-to-file.txt` should show the content as it is on HEAD.

Comment: Must say I have mixed feelings about this answer. It is factually correct and arguably addresses the question, but OP has told us what he's trying to do, and clearly `git diff` (or the diff views built into any of the UI tools that sit in front of git) is a more usable solution. Even OP's idea of keeping the original file outside git at least sets him up to use an external diff program more easily than with this command. This command (and the syntax that gives rise to it) may be useful to know for a relatively advanced git user, but IMO suggesting it here just makes git look hard to use

Comment: I understand... I'm just answering what the user wanted to see: the file as it is without his current changes on the working tree. Tim didn't ask how to see the differences (which is pointing to ```git diff```, for sure). And just in case, I don't see how it reflects into git being difficult, but that's another topic altogether, right? :-)

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. OP *did* ask how to tell the differences, first implicitly by saying "...so that I know what I have just changed...", and then pretty much explicitly by saying "Or shall i change my work style to avoid looking at the original file while changing it, by some other better work style?"  Answering this by suggesting an obscure syntax that doesn't even highlight the differences (but makes you find them yourself) absolutely gives the impression of git being hard to use.